# Continuity of $||\dot{}||_{1}$ as a function from $(\ell^2,||\dot{}||_{2}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $

Tags: analysis, continuity, normed-spaces

I have to check that the subset $M_{r}:={\{x \in \ell^{2} : ||x||_{1}\leq r \}}$ is closed on $(\ell^2,||\dot{}||_{2})$.

What I'm trying to do is to prove continuity of the $||\dot{}||_{1} :(\ell^2,||\dot{}||_{2})\rightarrow (\mathbb{R},|\dot{}|)$ norm on $\ell^{2}$ so that i can say $||\dot{}||_{1}^{-1}([0,r])=M_{r}$ is closed because of  continuity.

So I'm trying to prove, given arbitrary $\psi \in \ell^2$, we have that   $$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta>0 : \forall x \in \ell^2, ||\psi -x||_{2} < \delta \implies|||\psi||_{1}-||x||_{1}|<\epsilon$$ 
I tried to use the inverse triangle inequality as follows:
$$|||\psi||_{1}-||x||_{1}|=|(\sum_{k \geq 1}|\psi_{k}|-|x_{k}|)|\leq\sum_{k \geq 1}||\psi_{k}|-|x_{k}||\leq \sum_{k \geq 1}|\psi_{k}-x_{k}|=||\psi-x||_{1}$$
After writing that i noticed that it's just a direct application of the inequality on the 1 norm, either way, i'm trying to find a bound for the 1-norm using the 2-norm for continuity's sake so i can just pick a convenient $\delta$.

I feel i may have missed a fitting inequality that suffices to find an upper bound.

Btw: i have already proven that $\ell^1$ as a set is a subset of $\ell^2 $ with $\ell^2 $'s norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $\|\cdot\|_1$ is **not** continuous on $\ell^2$.  For example, if $X(n)$ is the sequence $(1/n, \ldots, 1/n, 0, \ldots)$ with $n$ $1/n$'s, we have  $\|X(n)\|_2 = 1/\sqrt{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ but $\|X(n)\|_1 = 1$.

To show $M_r$ is closed, note that if $x \notin M_r$, there is some finite $N$ such that $\sum_{k\le N} |x_k| > r$, and $\sum_{k \le N} |x_k|$ **is** continuous on $\ell^2$.

Comment: Ok, i get it is not continuous since with $\epsilon_0$=1/2 we cant find a $\delta$ small enough such that $||x(n)-0||_2$ < $\delta$  $\implies$ $||x(n)-0||_1$ < $\epsilon$, since the norm of the difference will always be 1. But i dont see where you are going with your hint, what you say is true since the tail of the series should aproach zero as it converges, but how can i get an open ball centered at x such that its outside $M_r$?

Comment: If $\sum_{k < N} |x_k| > r$, then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_k| > r$.